# Creating AWS s3 bucket without the UUID at the end

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

When I create a s3 bucket in AWS through terraform the s3 bucket gets created with a number (e.g `0000a211878e73ef26393003ea` ) at the end which is very annoying and ugly. Is there a way in I can create a globally unique name for a s3 bucket without the ugly number at the end?

e.g `test-s3-log-0000a211878e73ef26393003ea`. I prefer to use some unique name but not with ugly number at the end?

Any idea how we can achieve this using terraform?

Regards
Pradeep

Comment: Can you share your terraform code?

Answer (score 3):

The bucket name is in your control in fact. Do review your terraform code again.

You can hard code the bucket name without any random prefix or postfix.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket"
  acl    = "private"

  tags {
    Name        = "My bucket"
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}
```

bucket - (Optional, Forces new resource) The name of the bucket. **If omitted, Terraform will assign a random, unique name.**

Reference:

[terraform aws_s3_bucket](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am using bucket-prefix instead of "bucket" as I want to make the bucket name dynamic based on environment for example bucket-test-env, bucket-dev-env etc